# Why is the output containing - in this program?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, factorial

This is a program for calculating factorial of a number and I store it in a vector. The Program works fine for inputs upto 30, but for n=40 and greater, it produces a weird output.
eg.

input:

```
3

4

30

40
```

Output:

```
24

265252859812191058636308480000000

-190350521-236-6-6-5-745611269596115894272000000000
```

Where does this - sign come from?

```
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<int> solve(int n){
        if(n==1){
                vector<int> ans;
                ans.push_back(1);
                return ans; 
        }
        vector<int> b=solve(n-1);
        int temp=0,x=0;
        for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
                x=b[i]*n+temp;
                b[i]=x%10;
                temp=x/10;
        }
        if(temp!=0)
            b.push_back(temp);
        return b;
}   
    int main(){
            int t,n,i;
            scanf("%d",&t);
            while(t--){
                    scanf("%d",&n);
                    vector<int> ans=solve(n);
                    for(int j=ans.size()-1;j>=0;j--)
                             printf("%d",ans[j]);
                    printf("\n");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Because you are using _signed_ integers?

Comment: but I am computing the entire vector<int> int the code, so where does it go negative?

Comment: If you don't believe my, use a debugger to step through the code, and you will see that some of the values you push into the vector will be negative. See the answer from David Schwartz about the reason for that.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `temp` will be less than 10 when you `push_back` it into the vector at the end of `solve()`. When it exceeds 10, you get increasingly incorrect results. Follow the advice you've already been given: don't use signed integers to represent unsigned digits, use a larger capacity data type for temporary results, pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's integer overflow. A fixed-size integer can only hold so large a value and then it overflows. You probably want to use an arbitrary precision integer library like GMP.

Run your code with these changes and it will become obvious:

```
vector<int> solve(int n)
{
    if(n==1){
            vector<int> ans; 
            ans.push_back(1);
            return ans;
    }
    vector<int> b=solve(n-1);
    int temp=0,x=0;
    cout << "b.size=" << b.size() << ", n=" << n << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
            x=b[i]*n+temp;
            cout << "b[ " << i << "]=" << b[i] << ", temp= " << temp << ", x=" << x << endl;
            b[i]=x%10;
            temp=x/10;
    }
    if(temp!=0)
    {
        cout << "push_back(" << temp << ")" << endl;
        b.push_back(temp);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. It was my first thought too, but notice that he actually attempts to create his own bignum based on `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Nevertheless, it overflows. Figuring out where he goes wrong would require understanding how this was supposed to work. But if he just wants to figure out where it goes negative, the easiest way would be to add in sufficient logging to see where the values explode.